# What content type select in View related to email?

Tags: views, emails

I want to create a View. In my site there are lots of users are there, there is an email system i.e. send mail in these events : `At the time of registration, At the time of password reset, etc.`.

I want to create a View of type Email or related to Email so I want to show the following things inside View related email :

> Mail ID
>
> Subject
>
> Body

May anybody please help me to find out that what content type am I select for email while creating View. Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the content of users table so create a view as below

[image]

- Add the field `user:E-mail` field to list users E-mail ID's
- You could make use of [Views Send](https://drupal.org/project/views_send) Module
- Check this [Link](http://webwash.net/tutorials/send-emails-directly-views-using-views-send-drupal-7) this might help you understand Views Send Module

Comment: Thanks @Pravin for fast reply.. Pls check my updated question.

Comment: I updated my answer too.. Pls check whether it's useful

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get a view of mails sent from your site.

There's a module which does this for you. Much easier than setting up a view.

https://www.drupal.org/project/mail_logger

Comment: But I couldn't find a recommended release for drupal 7

Comment: If am I try this. Can development module help ? @munkiepus

Comment: Usually development modules aren't recommended for production sites. However as this is an admin function which won't be available to your users then you could test it yourself to see if it fulfills you requirements, and post back any bugs you might find to the issue queue for that module. In short, it's generally not recommended but you can mitigate the risk by testing yourself and contributing back to the community.